# Count wordpress code error

Tags: php, wordpress

Whats wrong with this code?

The count is working ok, but i this code is something wrong, can someone help me?

Thanks

```
<div <?php if (($count%3)==0) {post_class("$term_list one-third column ultimo")}
else {post_class("$term_list one-third column")} ?> >
```

Comment: What do you mean by **code error**? Is this code is within loop? Show the full loop code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it following way and make sure your `$count` and `$term_list` both variables are available within the current scope:

```
<?php if ( ($count % 3) == 0 ): $classes = array($term_list, 'one-third', 'column ultimo'); ?>
    <div <?php post_class($classes); ?>>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: One more thing, how i put count on this loop?

    <?php
    global $data;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' =>  $data['select_news']);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) :  $loop->the_post();  ?>

Thanks so much

Comment: @AdrianoVarlotta, You are welcome :-) I didn;t get it, where in the loop you want to put it inside the loop ?